# JSON Data into form fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm new to Javascript and Jquery so please excuse my ignorance. I'm trying to get my form fields to auto populate city and state based on zip code using JSON data I am pulling from an online .asp database. I am getting a successful JSON response with data that I can view in my dev tools window, but cannot get it to populate the fields on my form.

My Code is:

```
$(function() {

    var cache = {};
    var container = $("#validate");
    var errorDiv = container.find("div.text-error");

    /** Handle successful response */
    function handleResp(data)
    {
        // Check for error
        if (data.error_msg)
            errorDiv.text(data.error_msg);
        else if ("City" in data)
        {
            // Set city and state
            container.find("input[name='City']").val(data.City);
            container.find("input[name='State']").val(data.State);
        }
    }

    // Set up event handlers
    container.find("input[name='zipcode']").on("keyup change", function() {
        // Get zip code
        var zipcode = $(this).val().substring(0, 5);
        if (zipcode.length == 5 && /^[0-9]+$/.test(zipcode))
        {
            // Clear error
            errorDiv.empty();

            // Check cache
            if (zipcode in cache)
            {
                handleResp(cache[zipcode]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Build url
                var url = "http://dev.xxx.com/ASPFetchers/GetSPROCAsXML.asp?SPROC=EG_GetZipCodeInfo%20/"+(zipcode)+"/&F=JSON";

                // Make AJAX request
                $.ajax({
                    "url": url,
                    "dataType": "json"
                }).done(function(data) {
                    handleResp(data);

                    // Store in cache
                    cache[zipcode] = data;
                }).fail(function(data) {
                    if (data.responseText && (json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText)))
                    {
                        // Store in cache
                        cache[zipcode] = json;

                        // Check for error
                        if (json.error_msg)
                            errorDiv.text(json.error_msg);
                    }
                    else
                        errorDiv.text('Request failed.');
                });
            }
        }
    }).trigger("change");
});
```

My markup on my form is as follows:

```
    <div id="validate">                                                                             
<label>Zip Code</label>                         
<input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" size =" 5" maxlength = "5" />                            
<div class="text-error"></div>                                                      

<label>City</label>                         
<input type="text" name="City" id="City" />                                                 

<label>State</label>                            
<input type="text" name="State" id="State" />                           
<script type="text/javascript" src="../zip/includes/zip2.js"></script>      
</div>
</div>
```

The JSON I can view in my dev tools is(based on zipcode 06702):

```
{"items":[{"City":"WATERBURY","County":"NEW%20HAVEN","State":"CT","StateName":"CONNECTICUT","Latitude":"0.7252836","Longitude":"-1.274794"},
```

Can anyone help me solve how to get the information from this string and have it populate the "City" and "State" field? Thank You for your time and knowledge.

Comment: Looks like it's time to learn how to use a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the data you posted here, you will need to use the `items` array inside of your data.

```
container.find('input[name="City"]').val(data.items[0].City);
container.find('input[name="State"]').val(data.items[0].StateName);
```

Comment: I've also tried this, and again, nothing is populated in the fields

Comment: @Cinq Inside of `handleResp` do a `console.log` of `data`.  Is what is posted the same exact response as you posted in your question?  If so, please note that you have to change the `else if('City' in data)` check to `else if('City' in data.items[0])`

Comment: The else if('City' in data.items[0]) fixed my issue, and now both fields are populating correctly. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The object that is returned looks is an **array of objects**.

So first get the items array and refer the 1st item inside it.

```
function handleResp(data) {
        // Check for error
        if (data.error_msg)
            errorDiv.text(data.error_msg);
        else if ("City" in data) {
            var info = data.items[0];
            // Set city and state
            container.find("input[name='City']").val(info.City);
            container.find("input[name='State']").val(info.State);
        }
    }
```